# invalid use of template-name ‘boost::asio::strand’ without an argument list

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I have an older program that I want to compile on Centos 8 with GCC 8.3.1. The make command looks like this:

```
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -std=c++11

all: my_prog

my_prog: my_prog.o
    g++ my_prog.o -o my_prog -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lsecond_level_include -lthird_level_include -lboost_regex -lboost_program_options `mysql_config --libs`
```

Here is the output for `make`:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/redisclient/redissyncclient.h:16,
                 from /usr/local/include/third_level_include.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/local/include/second_level_include.hpp:40,
                 from my_prog.cpp:9:
/usr/local/include/redisclient/impl/redisclientimpl.h:72:5: error: invalid use of template-name ‘boost::asio::strand’ without an argument list
     boost::asio::strand strand;
     ^~~~~
/usr/local/include/redisclient/impl/redisclientimpl.h:72:5: note: class template argument deduction is only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17
In file included from /usr/local/include/redisclient/impl/redisclientimpl.h:13,
                 from /usr/local/include/redisclient/redissyncclient.h:16,
                 from /usr/local/include/third_level_include.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/local/include/second_level_include.hpp:40,
from my_prog.cpp:9:
/usr/include/boost/asio/strand.hpp:29:7: note: ‘template<class Executor> class boost::asio::strand’ declared here
 class strand
       ^~~~~~
```

[snip lots of output]

So I did what it suggested and replaced `-std=c++11` with `-std=gnu++17` and now
I get this:

```
g++ -O2 -std=gnu++17   -c -o my_prog.o my_prog.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/redisclient/redissyncclient.h:16,
                 from /usr/local/include/third_level_include.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/local/include/second_level_include.hpp:40,
                 from my_prog.cpp:9:
/usr/local/include/redisclient/impl/redisclientimpl.h:72:5: error: invalid use of template-name ‘boost::asio::strand’ without an argument list
     boost::asio::strand strand;
     ^~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: my_prog.o] Error 1
```

Considering that I'm not going to be changing the third party library code from Redis, is there a compiler flag or something I can use to make this error go away? The code compiled once upon a time with GCC 4.4.7 on Centos 6.

**EDIT: here is the file that is the source of the error**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) Alex Nekipelov (alex@nekipelov.net)
 * License: MIT
 */

#ifndef REDISCLIENT_REDISCLIENTIMPL_H
#define REDISCLIENT_REDISCLIENTIMPL_H

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <map>

#include "../redisparser.h"
#include "../redisbuffer.h"
#include "../config.h"

class RedisClientImpl : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<RedisClientImpl> {
public:
    enum State {
        NotConnected,
        Connected,
        Subscribed,
        Closed
    };  

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL RedisClientImpl(boost::asio::io_service &ioService);
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL ~RedisClientImpl();

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void handleAsyncConnect(
            const boost::system::error_code &ec,
          const boost::function<void(bool, const std::string &)> &handler);

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void close();

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL State getState() const;

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL static std::vector<char> makeCommand(const std::vector<RedisBuffer> &items);

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL RedisValue doSyncCommand(const std::vector<RedisBuffer> &buff);

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void doAsyncCommand(
            const std::vector<char> &buff,
            const boost::function<void(const RedisValue &)> &handler);

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void sendNextCommand();
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void processMessage();
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void doProcessMessage(const RedisValue &v);
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void asyncWrite(const boost::system::error_code &ec, const size_t);
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void asyncRead(const boost::system::error_code &ec, const size_t);

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL void onRedisError(const RedisValue &);
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL static void defaulErrorHandler(const std::string &s);

    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL static void append(std::vector<char> &vec, const RedisBuffer &buf);
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL static void append(std::vector<char> &vec, const std::string &s);
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL static void append(std::vector<char> &vec, const char *s);
    REDIS_CLIENT_DECL static void append(std::vector<char> &vec, char c);
    template<size_t size>
    static inline void append(std::vector<char> &vec, const char (&s)[size]);

    template<typename Handler>
    inline void post(const Handler &handler);

    boost::asio::strand strand; // Here it is!
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    RedisParser redisParser;
    boost::array<char, 4096> buf;
    size_t subscribeSeq;
    typedef std::pair<size_t, boost::function<void(const std::vector<char> &buf)> > MsgHandlerType;
    typedef boost::function<void(const std::vector<char> &buf)> SingleShotHandlerType;

    typedef std::multimap<std::string, MsgHandlerType> MsgHandlersMap;
    typedef std::multimap<std::string, SingleShotHandlerType> SingleShotHandlersMap;

    std::queue<boost::function<void(const RedisValue &v)> > handlers;
    MsgHandlersMap msgHandlers;
    SingleShotHandlersMap singleShotMsgHandlers;

    struct QueueItem {
        boost::function<void(const RedisValue &)> handler;
        boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > buff;
    };

    std::queue<QueueItem> queue;

    boost::function<void(const std::string &)> errorHandler;
    State state;
};

template<size_t size>
void RedisClientImpl::append(std::vector<char> &vec, const char (&s)[size])
{
    vec.insert(vec.end(), s, s + size);
}

template<typename Handler>
inline void RedisClientImpl::post(const Handler &handler)
{
    strand.post(handler);
}


#ifdef REDIS_CLIENT_HEADER_ONLY
#include "redisclientimpl.cpp"
#endif

#endif // REDISCLIENT_REDISCLIENTIMPL_H
```

Comment: Did you... include everything but the code? That's going to be pretty hard to fix.

Comment: Yeah, that might help. Added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### UPDATE
>
> You're using an old version of that library. Use v0.6.1 or higher:
> https://github.com/nekipelov/redisclient/pull/53

---

All executor interfaces have been [upgraded a (long) while ago](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html).

Strands used to be nested typedefs (and there is still one for "legacy" compatibility in `io_service` if that is enabled).

However, the new type succeeding is is `boost::asio::strand<Executor>` (so e.g. `boost::asio::io_context::executor_type`). You can easily make a strand for any executor, e.g.:

```
 auto s = make_strand(io_object.get_executor());
```

What you are seeing is apparent mix-up of these names. I suspect it may have to do with

- local typedefs that alias `strand`
- local variables named `strand` (though I don't see immediately how that would lead to the exact message mposted)
- most likely: you have a `using namespace` that pulls in the new `strand` template

With this information, you should be able to sort it out.

Of course, had you posted the code, we could have shown it for you.

Comment: That is a reasonable request, I have added the code, I made a comment at line 72 per the compiler error.

Comment: I didn't realize it was an external library. You could just link to that of course (assuming https://github.com/nekipelov/redisclient)

Comment: I cannot repro. What version (git commit) of the library do you use? What version of Boost do you use? Please show a minimal example program that fails to compile. I expect a few includes + `int main() {}` because you've not thought it necessary to include code before.

Comment: With Boost 1.77 and amalgamated `redisclient.h` from latest master (fbf052ef8e3772d17) this compiles fine in c++11: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/PQC6cy3P9k/ So, I still suspect ill-chosen macros or `using`-directives.

Comment: Looks like your errors have been fixed YEARS ago: https://github.com/nekipelov/redisclient/pull/53 (the fix landed in Feb 2018). v0.6.1 includes that fix (also Feb 2018). Indeed, going back to v0.6.0 reproduces your error.

Comment: Based on the line number you mentioned, you were using v0.4 (Aug 2016).

Comment: the code is indeed very old. Thanks for the illustration above.